# Deserializing a List<Object> Collection without Creating an extra class in .NET 6

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, deserialization

Currently, I am trying to deserialize an XML structure into a typed object in C#. First of all, the targeting XML structure is identical to the structure of the object (entity model), as shown in the following two pictures:

[image]

[image]

How can I deserialize the list element, without creating an extra class that extends the Collection List. If that is not possible with the DataContractSerializer, I am fine with deserializing in any other elegant way. The class structure has to be like this, because the functionality of the entity framework relies on it. I am using this to deserialize XML files from a local directory and save the entity in the database using EF 6. I hope there is an elegant solution to this. I am also open to library recommendations or other approaches to solving this problem.

That is the code that uses the deserialization:

[image]

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: In my experience, most serializers handle common generic collections like `List<MyClass>` or `MyClass[]` just fine. So what problem do you have? Note that trying to deserialize something into `List<object>` is very different, since there is no way to tell what type each object in the list should be.

Comment: Yes a List of an object is fine, but this time the List<object (other type than the one that gets deserialized) > is nested in another object, which gets deserialized. I dont know if this is also handled fine by the serializer

Comment: Nested properties are typically handled just fine. As long as all the types matches the data to deserialize well enough. You might need to do something special if you have loops in your object graph, but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just deserialize as an array `TModel[]` or `List<TModel>`:

```
_serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TModel[]));
```

or:

```
_serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<TModel>));
```

> **[Why not inherit from List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1690217)**
> There is *almost never* a good reason to *"extends the Collection List"* so don't be thinking that this is even an option, there is usually a much simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this will not solve my issue, because i want to serialize one TModel object that has a List<object> as a property, which i could not deserialize yet

Comment: There is no List<object> in your example, but you are correct, with untyped objects the only way to deserialize would be to _know_ the type first, or use a converter that tries to map against a list of known types. Update your example to include these cases so we can assist you further